# Is it possible to use Dialogflow CX agents to automate responses to private messages on Linkedin?

Tags: python, dialogflow-cx

I'm looking for a solution since few times to generate automatic answers to people which are answering me to my private messages on LinkedIn.

Knowing that I am a beginner in python (I would prefer to use python), what would be the best strategy to automate my responses with Linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use DialogFlow and connect it to the Linkedin API. You can see more functions of the [Linkedin API](https://pipedream.com/apps/google-dialogflow/integrations/linkedin).

You can see the code to connect the Linkedin API below:

```
return await require("@pipedreamhq/platform").axios(this, {
  url: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${auths.linkedin.oauth_access_token}`,
  },
})
```

Additionally, you can see official documentation about the Linkedin API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/?context=linkedin/context).

There are more solutions to automate, but you have to pay monthly, like hootsuite or expandi.io.

You can see these tutorials of how to use [DialogFlow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/setup#python).

**EDIT**

You should use linkedin API directly. There a lot of [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/) about it.

You can see this code example to send message.

```
function message($subject, $body, $recipients)
{
    if (!is_array($recipients)) {
        throw new Exception('Recipients must be suplied as an array');
    }

    // Start document
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

    // Create element for recipients and add each recipient as a node
    $elemRecipients = $xml->createElement('recipients');
    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
        // Create person node

        $person = $xml->createElement('person');
        $person->setAttribute('path', '/people/' . (string) $recipient);

        // Create recipient node
        $elemRecipient = $xml->createElement('recipient');
        $elemRecipient->appendChild($person);

        // Add recipient to recipients node
        $elemRecipients->appendChild($elemRecipient);

    }


    // Create mailbox node and add recipients, body and subject
    $elemMailbox = $xml->createElement('mailbox-item');
    $elemMailbox->appendChild($elemRecipients);
    $elemMailbox->appendChild($xml->createElement('body', ($body)));
    $elemMailbox->appendChild($xml->createElement('subject', ($subject)));

    // Append parent node to document
    $xml->appendChild($elemMailbox);

    $response = fetch('POST','/v1/people/~/mailbox', $xml->saveXML());

    return ($response);
}


function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
    $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
        'format' => 'json',
    );

    // Need to use HTTPS
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request


    $context = stream_context_create(
        array('http' =>
            array('method' => $method,

                'header'=> "Content-Type:text/xml\r\n"
                    . "Content-Length: " . strlen($body) . "\r\n",
                'content' => ($body)
            )
        )
    );


    // Hocus Pocus
    $fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $result =json_decode($response,true);

    return $result;}
message('Subject', 'body', array('id'));
```

Uses a linkedin "user ids" (array of ids).

You can se mor[e code examples](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin) in Python, starting from the begining to make a connection to python.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.
I don't see any linkedin API in pipedream to answer private message with dialogflow. Would you have a recommandation to give me ? Should I use linkedin API directly without using pipedream ? (I'm juste discovering pipedream)

Comment: @FrancNovation I add more information.